# Disable Javascript Debugging in IE Console

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging, console

I am working on a site which has been around for the best part of ten years, and has been at the hands of multiple developers. As such, it has some expected 'quirks'.

The issues I have, is that I want to test for previous versions of IE, but when I use the Emulator in the console (IE11), the moment I select a previous version (let's say IE9) it automatically runs the JavaScript Debugger and pauses the script.

This is making it very difficult for me to go through the site and test for any cosmetic and functional issues. The thing is, I have never had this happen before, so I don't understand it! (I'm no JavaScript ninja).

I just want to disable this debugging.

Edit:

It seems to be this code in jQuery throwing the error.

```
return val === undefined ?
    support.attributes || !documentIsHTML ?
        elem.getAttribute( name ) :
        (val = elem.getAttributeNode(name)) && val.specified ?
            val.value :
            null :
    val;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In the F12 Debugger tab, select "Never break on exceptions" like this ...

[image]

That should do it.